# Calling method in main function

Tags: java, class, methods, nested-loops

I'm just trying to call nested loops method to main function. I got 2 errors `cannot be resolved or is not a field` and `the method patternA() is undefined for the type classNested`. I know it's really common error but I still couldn't find a way to solve it.

Here's my main class

```
package nomerTuhuh;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class nestedLoops {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
          // get the total number of lines n.

         classNested result = new classNested();
         Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

          System.out.print("Enter the number of lines:");
          result.n=sc.nextInt(); <-- error "cannot be resolved or is not a field"

         result.patternA(); <-- error "the method patternA() is undefined for the type classNested"
         }

        }
```

And here's the method

```
package nomerTuhuh;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class classNested {
      public int n;


      void patternA(){

      // Loop through the lines from 1 to n
      System.out.println("Pattern A");
      for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {

       // Printing number increamentally from 1 to line number j
       for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        System.out.print(j + " ");
       }
       System.out.println();

      }

    }
}
```

1st Error:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
n cannot be resolved or is not a field  nestedLoops.java    /chapter1/src/nomerTuhuh    line 14 Java Problem
```

2nd Error:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The method patternA() is undefined for the type classNested nestedLoops.java    /chapter1/src/nomerTuhuh    line 16 Java Problem
```

Can anyone please tell me what's wrong? Thank you.

Comment: how did you compile your `.java` files?

Comment: Your code works. Maybe you have naming collision.

Comment: Can you please make first letter capital for your class names.

Comment: Can you please provide the *exact* stack trace you are getting right now after running your `nestedLoops` class ? Are you using any IDE like eclipse, intelliJ or running it from the command line ?

Comment: Nothing wrong at coding, code works fine. check other configurations

Comment: @MarounMaroun I actually have different programs in the same project but each program is inside different package. Does that will be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my code works... I haven't tried to run it. I just stuck at the error reported but I'm not trying to ignore it and just run it. When I run it, the error magically disappear.
I'm using eclipse btw.

Answer (score -4):

n variable should be static so that it can be accessed.
and your patternA() should be declared public something like this

```
public static int n;
public void patternA()
{}
```

Comment: No. It works without making `n` static and without the need to change the default package modifier.